# Building up an NSCalendarUnit value from an array of individual units

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am trying to calculate the number of years/days/mins/etc until a certain `NSDate`. I am doing:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:date options:0];
```

I am trying to allow the user to select which components they want to see. Say I have an array containing they want `NSCalendarUnitYear` and `NSCalendarUnitMinute`. How do I concatenate these into the `(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMinute)`?

I tried:

```
NSCalendarUnit *units;
for (NSCalendarUnit *unit in arrayOfUnits) {
    units = units | unit;
}
```

but this does not compile. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSCalendarUnit` isn't an object, it's an `enum`; you can't store one in an `NSArray`. You could wrap it up in an `NSNumber` that is stored in the array, but then you have to unwrap it before you try to do bitwise operations.

That would look like this:

```
NSNumber * userUnitNumber = @(userChosenCalendarUnit);

[arrayOfUnits addObject:calUnitNumber];

// Initialize this to zero or it will contain garbage 
// and you'll get bizarre results!
NSCalendarUnit finalUnits = 0;

for( NSNumber * unitNumber in arrayOfUnits ){
    // The datatype for an NSCalendarUnit is NSUInteger
    finalUnits |= [unitNumber unsignedIntegerValue];
}
```

But I'm not sure why you're not just building up the final value as you get input from the user; there doesn't seem to be any reason to keep these things in an array in the first place. The bitmask contains as much information as an array would in much less space (which is its entire reason for existence).

Comment: I guess the reason for the array would be that later I need a way for the user to see which units have been selected. There would be no way decipher which ones had been selected from the final value of finalUnits

Comment: Sure there is. `if( finalUnits & NSCalendarUnitMinute )`, e.g., will tell you if "minute" is one of the set flags in the mask.